# Can't install discord.js / can't find module discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

I attempt to install Discord.JS by running `npm install discord.js` and it looks like it works, but it doesn't.

I get this error when running the `index.js` file, but it gives an error stating that `discord.js` is not found. So, I try to install it again:

```bsh
PS G:\My Drive\coding\node.js\bot> npm install https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js.git
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN bot@0.0.1 No repository field.

+ discord.js@12.0.2
added 15 packages from 17 contributors and audited 15 packages in 97.377s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Then I run the `index.js` file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const botCommands = require('./commands');
const { prefix, token } = require('./cfg.json');

bot.login(TOKEN);

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});
```

This is the result displayed in console:

```bsh
PS G:\My Drive\coding\node.js\bot> node .
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './commands'
Require stack:
- G:\My Drive\coding\node.js\bot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\My Drive\coding\node.js\bot\index.js:3:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'G:\\My Drive\\coding\\node.js\\bot\\index.js' ]
}
```

Side note: Before I ran `index.js`, I ran `npm init -y` to create a package.

P.S: English is not my first language

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module './commands'`

Comment: yeah my bad.  real sorry.

Comment: i think the 1st time discord.js failed to install and i run the file multiple times and it has different results and i didnt notice it. Case Closed.  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot find the /commands folder - are you sure it is there? - make sure it is in the folder `'G:\My Drive\coding\node.js\bot\'`.

Comment: It's not the commands folder it's searching for. When requiring a file with no extension, node automatically appends `.js` to it, so it's actually searching for `commands.js`.

Comment: I didn't write the code. I'm just stating what the code he wrote does.

Comment: well actually lol, first of all, thanks. but the problem is fixed long time ago.
what actually the problem is that i thought it has problem accessing discord.js. and now it's case closed.  the next problem i've also fixed it. it's just `fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));`
And, it just run fine.  This whole question is case closed.  it's just me being stupid to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. First of all, it says the module "./commands" is not found, discord.js does exist.

The reason is, you are trying to import a folder. Node.js does not work that way.

You have to delete the line with the require("./commands") and replace it with something like this:

```js
var botCommands = fs.readdirSync('./commands/');
```

That will return an array of file names in that directory.

Then, go on with whatever you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct folder and you have `commands` folder in `G:\My Drive\coding\node.js\bot`

Comment: Just check it. There are many possibilities

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your 3rd line ou have require the commands

If you have commands folder do this

```js
fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like

```
bot.on('message', message => {

  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
     let rawA = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
     let cmd = rawA[0];
     let rawB = rawA.join(' ');
     let args = rawB.slice(cmd.length).split(' ');
  
     let cmdFile = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`);
     cmdFile.run(bot, message, args);
  }
}
```

But if you use this, you need this in your command file:

```
exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ya see, If it says "commands is not found" then it could be that your folder might be wrong, double-check the capatalization and lowercases. And if still its showing wrong.

Make sure that your commands folder is actually in this directory.

```
G:\\My Drive\\coding\\node.js\\bot\\index.js
```

Hope this helped!